# Angular 17 SSR [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I just upgraded Angular to version 17 and now im getting a SSR error:

> [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /chunk-TAOE3DWL.mjs:
> |- TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
> at Function.getPrototypeOf ()
> at node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/utils.js (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/utils.js:34:39)
> at __require2 (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/.angular/vite-root/hi-frontend/chunk-LO3AJX6B.mjs:54:50)
> at node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL.js (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/URL.js:4:15)
> at __require2 (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/.angular/vite-root/hi-frontend/chunk-LO3AJX6B.mjs:54:50)
> at node_modules/whatwg-url/webidl2js-wrapper.js (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/node_modules/whatwg-url/webidl2js-wrapper.js:3:13)
> at __require2 (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/.angular/vite-root/hi-frontend/chunk-LO3AJX6B.mjs:54:50)
> at node_modules/whatwg-url/index.js (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/node_modules/whatwg-url/index.js:3:34)
> at __require2 (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/.angular/vite-root/hi-frontend/chunk-LO3AJX6B.mjs:54:50)
> at node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js (/home/dej/src/hi-frontend/node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js:7:19)

After narrowing it down I noticed that its my get functions in my services that are leading to this error. The get functions look like this:

```
    getUser(): Observable<User> {
        let url = this.domain + this.prefix + '/user/';
        return this.http.get<User>(url).pipe(
            map(user => new User().deserialize(user))
        );
    }
```

The problem lies in `new User().deserialize(user)`, if i for example dont deserialize the response from the server the error goes away. But I need to deserialize into the User class.

The User class looks like this:

```
export interface Deserializable {
    deserialize(input: any): this;
}

export class User implements Deserializable {
    id: number;

    deserialize(input: any): this {
        Object.assign(this, input);
        return this;
    }

    getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

I tried adding checks for null or undefined in deserialize but its still not working:

```
deserialize(input: any): this {
    if (input == null || input == undefined)
        return this;

    Object.assign(this, input);
    return this;
}
```

Any ideas why this is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have error on whatwg-url .
update it to the last version with npm.

Comment: I'm running the latest version on whatwg-url, see my updated post above, I did find where the error originates but not the solution yet.